# Find information about IIS Thread Pool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, resource-monitor

I am developing web app with `ASP.NET MVC` and hosting it on `IIS7.5` I would like to know how much my app use threads in `Thread Pool` and how much threads left.

I have looking for information about monitoring IIS7.5 Thread Pool for several days without any luck. I do not find any resource monitor counter which could show this data, also I do not find a way to access `Thread Pool` information from ASP.NET app itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to be helpful (even though it was marked as potentially out of date): [How To: Monitor the ASP.NET Thread Pool Using Custom Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650682.aspx)

Also: [Similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338884/monitor-net-threads)